# ofstream. Записать char в начало файла

Tags: c++, файлы, битовые-операции, c++17

Собственно, есть *std::ofstream file*

Я открываю его для бинарной записи *std::ios::out | std::ios::binary*

Пишу что-то, например

```
(*treeFile).write((char*) & (rootTree->c), sizeof(rootTree->c))
```

А после мне нужно в начало файла записать *char abc*

Как это можно сделать без потери текущего содержимого файла?

Comment: Переписать в новый файл. Что написано пером - не вырубишь топором, в файле можно только **до**писать и **пере**писать.

Comment: ещё на практике можно заранее оставить место для одного байта, а ещё писать во временный буфер вместо файла, например, с помощью `std::stringstream`.

Comment: @Fat-Zer а можно поподробней насчет "оставить место для одного байта"

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG, изначально записать временное значение: `treeFile->put(0)`, записать всё что нужно, а затем переместить указатель чтения в начало: `treeFile->seekp(0)` и записать нормальное значение: `treeFile->put(abc)`... ИМХО на практике к этому стоит прибегать только при необходимости... в остальном  стоит руководствоваться принципом «сначала подготовил данные, а потом записал».

Comment: @Fat-Zer огромное спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, **@Fat-Zer**

> @AlrottSlimRG, изначально записать временное значение:
>   treeFile->put(0), записать всё что нужно, а затем переместить
>   указатель чтения в начало: treeFile->seekp(0) и записать нормальное
>   значение: treeFile->put(abc)... ИМХО на практике к этому стоит
>   прибегать только при необходимости... в остальном стоит
>   руководствоваться принципом «сначала подготовил данные, а потом
>   записал».